# ruby: use module include in instance method of class

Tags: ruby, module

Have a look at the code below

```
initshared.rb
module InitShared
  def init_shared
    @shared_obj = "foobar"
  end
end
```

myclass.rb

```
class MyClass
  def initialize()
  end
  def init
    file_name = Dir.pwd+"/initshared.rb"
    if File.file?(file_name)
      require file_name
      include InitShared
      if self.respond_to?'init_shared'
        init_shared
        puts @shared_obj
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The include InitShared dosn't work since its inside the method .

I want to check for the file and then include the module and then access the variables in that module.

Comment: You don't need an empty `initialize` method.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using Samnang's

```
singleton_class.send(:include, InitShared)
```

you can also use

```
extend InitShared
```

It does the same, but is version independent. It will include the module only into the objects own singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

```
module InitShared
  def init_shared
    @shared_obj = "foobar"
  end
end

class MyClass
  def init
    if true
      self.class.send(:include, InitShared)

      if self.respond_to?'init_shared'
        init_shared
        puts @shared_obj
      end
    end
  end
end

MyClass.new.init
```

:include is a private class method, so you can't call it in instance level method. Another solution if you want to include that module only for specific instance you can replace the line with :include with this line:

```
# Ruby 1.9.2
self.singleton_class.send(:include, InitShared)

# Ruby 1.8.x
singleton_class = class << self; self; end
singleton_class.send(:include, InitShared)
```